# raw_input not returning correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def daenerys():
    Name = raw_input("Who goes there?")

    if ("Daenerys of the House Targaryen, the First of Her Name, The Unburnt, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar and the First Men, Queen of Meereen, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea, Protector of the Realm, Lady Regnant of the Seven Kingdoms, Breaker of Chains and Mother of Dragons"):
        print("Welcome, Daenerys.")
    elif ("DHTFHNUQARFMQMKGSPRLRSKBCMD"):
        print("Welcome, Daenerys.")
    elif ("Dany"):
        print("Dany who?")
    else:
        print("Move along, now")

daenerys()
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: How is python supposed to know that you're trying to check the value of the `Name` variable if your if statements look like `if ("Dany"):`?

Comment: Sorry, my bio was deleted after I made an edit, but the computer takes my first if statement to be true  no matter what I feed the raw_input and returns the first print statement.

Comment: Because non-empty strings are considered [truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39983695/6779307).

Comment: You aren't comparing your values to the `Name` variable, thus there is no comparison. So your first `if` statement will evaluate to `True` every time

Comment: Much appreciated guys, it truly has been a long night.

Comment: expression not found, if elif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not even checking the Name variable. You should be doing

```
def daenerys():
    Name = raw_input("Who goes there?")

    if (Name == "Daenerys of the House Targaryen, the First of Her Name, The Unburnt, Queen of the Andals, the Rhoynar and the First Men, Queen of Meereen, Khaleesi of the Great Grass Sea, Protector of the Realm, Lady Regnant of the Seven Kingdoms, Breaker of Chains and Mother of Dragons"):
        print("Welcome, Daenerys.")
    elif (Name == "DHTFHNUQARFMQMKGSPRLRSKBCMD"):
        print("Welcome, Daenerys.")
    elif (Name == "Dany"):
        print("Dany who?")
    else:
        print("Move along, now")

daenerys()
```

This will actually check to see if the variable `Name` is equal to the strings.